# Exchange Online user limit and license mixing

Tags: office365

I have looked all over and can't seem to find a limit for how many Exchange Online P1 (or Kiosk) users I can have for a single domain.

Is it possible to mix Exchange Online P1, Business Premium and E1/E3 licenses for users under the same domain? I have seen the 300 user limit for Business accounts, but how would that apply when there are say 2000 Exhange Online P1 and 200 Business Premium for the same domain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from my license partner saying that you can (in theory) mix and match licenses. You just have to make sure each user gets the features they actually need with the assigned license or licenses. Problems will arise if a given feature is not supported by the license of all users of the feature.

I've also mixed several Exchange Online P1/P2 and the different Office Business licenses to test without problems.